# Having trouble doing a POST request with RESTKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to post some data (an authentication token for a website, to be specific) with RESTKit and I'm having trouble. Each time I run the method, I get this:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '`RKRequestDescriptor` objects must be initialized 
with a mapping whose target class is `NSMutableDictionary`, got 'Login' (see 
`[RKObjectMapping requestMapping]`)'
```

Also, there are many 'Incompatible pointer types' warnings in the code.

Here is my method which is really ugly and bad, and I would like some help fixing up. I do a `[self postToken]` inside an IBAction method when a button is pressed. I am getting variable userAuthToken from another file, where it is set using with the json response from a POST request not using RESTKit. I will eventually convert that POST to RESTKit when I know how to successfully. The method "userAuthTokenMethod" is in the same file as the "postToken" method, and it allows me to use the userAuthToken object, which is initialized in AppDelegate so it acts as a global variable.

```
- (void)postToken
{        
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Login class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"token": @"token"}];
    NSIndexSet *statusCodeSet = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);
    RKResponseDescriptor *tokenResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping method:nil pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:statusCodeSet];
    RKRequestDescriptor *tokenRequestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:mapping objectClass:self rootKeyPath:nil method:nil];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addRequestDescriptor:tokenRequestDescriptor];
    RKObjectManager *tokenManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://websitetest.com/doctors/find"]];
    [tokenManager addResponseDescriptor:tokenResponseDescriptor];
    [tokenManager addRequestDescriptor:tokenRequestDescriptor];
    [tokenManager postObject:[[self userAuthTokenMethod] userAuthToken] path:nil parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];


    NSURL *tokenURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://websitetest.com/doctors/find?name=%@&location=%@",nameIDTextField.text, locationTextField.text];
    NSMutableURLRequest *tokenRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tokenURL]];
    RKObjectManager *tokenObjectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tokenURL]];
    [tokenObjectManager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"Auth-Token" value:[[self network360Edge] userAuthToken]];
    RKObjectRequestOperation *tokenOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:tokenRequest responseDescriptors:@[tokenResponseDescriptor]];
    NSLog(@"Token being POSTed ==> %@", [[self userAuthTokenMethod] userAuthToken]);
    [tokenOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result){
        NSLog(@"Response for POST request with token ==> %@", [result array]);
    }failure:nil];
    [tokenOperation start];
}
```

Here is the code for my mapping provider file called MappingProvider:

```
//MappingProvider.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>

@interface MappingProvider : NSObject

+(RKMapping *)tokenMapping;

@end

//MappingProvider.m
#import "MappingProvider.h"
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import "Login.h"

@implementation MappingProvider

+(RKMapping *)tokenMapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *tokenMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Login class]];
    [tokenMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"token"]];
    return tokenMapping;
}

@end
```

Here is the code for the Login file where 'token' is initialized:

```
//Login.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Login : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString *token;

@end
```

I'm very new to RESTKit and somewhat new with Objective-C (I've been coding in it for about a month). I would appreciate all help in fixing up my code.

Comment: I think you should not use nil in place of keypath in ResponseDescriptor. Rather you can use empty string. And trying setting the request method in ResponseDescriptor as RKRequestMethodPOST/GET as applicable. Moreover, as RKObjectManager is a shared class, you are adding same response descriptor more than once to that by adding descriptors to RKObjectManager and TokenManager.

Comment: Remove the line which is adding tokenRequestDescriptor to [RKObjectManager sharedManager].

Comment: I have the exctly same issue with you, i want to know did you have your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but the issue is that requests should use mapping without class specification, because requests use descriptors that specify class (see 2 lines below), like this:

```
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
```

Probably you also have issue in line:

```
RKRequestDescriptor *tokenRequestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:mapping objectClass:self rootKeyPath:nil method:nil];
```

more concretely in **objectClass:self**, it should be **objectClass:[self class]** or the needed class that contains **token** property, like this:

```
RKRequestDescriptor *tokenRequestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[self class] rootKeyPath:nil method:nil];
```

Hope this helps